# Blackberry VerticalfieldManager virtual scroll view size too large

Tags: blackberry, scrollview

Developing on the blackberry (OS 7.0) and I have an extended Vertical Field manager created as such:

```
_myVFM = new MyViewManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.USE_ALL_HEIGHT | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL){};
```

However, when I scroll the view, the virtual scroll view size appears way too big. 
i.e, I can scroll quite alot further down than is needed and I cant work out why?

Any body any quick ideas? I do have a background image in there that is created as such:

```
public void paint(Graphics graphics)
{
    Bitmap backgroundBitmap = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("bg.png");
    Bitmap newBackground = new Bitmap(Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight());
    backgroundBitmap.scaleInto(newBackground, Bitmap.FILTER_LANCZOS, Bitmap.SCALE_TO_FILL);

    graphics.clear();
    graphics.drawBitmap(0, 0, Display.getWidth(),            
             Display.getHeight(), newBackground, 0, 0);                 
    super.paint(graphics);
}
```

Please and thanks,

Burrows

Comment: What is the reason for extending the default `VerticalFieldManager`? And you can completely remove the implementation of `paint` method, and use `setBackground` method to set the background to your fieldManager (supported from API 5 or later I think). You can use `BackgroundFactory` class for creating fancy background that uses image.

Comment: Ok, let me have a look - I only extended it to make use of paint method. .. ill let you know how I get on, thanks.

Comment: You need to do something like this, https://gist.github.com/3248319.

Comment: is `paint()` really the only thing you've overridden in `VerticalFieldManager`?  please post your whole class ... thanks.

Comment: Yeah only paint is overridden. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public MyScreen() {
    super(NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL);
```

I managed to fix the issue in my extension of MainScreen using 'NO_VERTICAL_SCROLL' style parameter

Combined with Rupak's suggestion of setting the Background in the constructor of my Vertical Field Manager rather than overriding paint (
https://gist.github.com/3248319)

everything seems Good now - thanks all for your help.

Burrows

Answer (score 0):

No need to USE_ALL_HEIGHT in your constructor.

// instead use this

```
_myVFM = new MyViewManager(Manager.USE_ALL_WIDTH | Manager.VERTICAL_SCROLL){};
```

Comment: Sadly that dont make any difference to me. Im now back trying to find a solution and will post up if and when done! cheers though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the method to define the height of the manager

```
protected void setExtent(int width, int height) {
    super.setExtent(width, myHeight);
}
```

To not repeat the background image is necessary to redefine the following method, returning false

```
protected boolean isScrollCopyable() {
    return false;
}
```

Another comment is that it is a bad practice to obtain an image from the paint method. What you are doing is every time you call the paint method is going to get this image.
It's best to get the image once and then use it.